# GDataXMLDocument Memory Increase

Tags: iphone, ios, memory, memory-management, xml-parsing

Hi all i am using the rss reader provided by [Ray](http://%28http://www.raywenderlich.com/2636/how-to-make-a-simple-rss-reader-iphone-app-tutorial%29)  which is great. The app needs to parse a rather large xml file which is approx 7MB. The process works fine and i can download and parse the content and save it into a database. However, i have a major problem with Memory. When running in Instruments it goes up to around 30mb and although its only for 30-40 seconds it crashes the app as i perform the download and parsing on first run.

Any help on this would be appreciated. The code which i believe causes the main problem is:

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {


    //////// problem code /////////
        NSError *error;

    GDataXMLDocument *doc = [[GDataXMLDocument alloc] initWithData:[request responseData] 
                                                       options:0 error:&error];
    [_queue addOperationWithBlock:^{

    if (doc == nil) { 


    } else {

        entries = [NSMutableArray array];

        [self parseFeed:doc.rootElement entries:entries];                

        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{

            for (RSSEntry *entry in entries) {

                int insertIdx = [_allEntries indexForInsertingObject:entry sortedUsingBlock:^(id a, id b) {
                    RSSEntry *entry1 = (RSSEntry *) a;
                    RSSEntry *entry2 = (RSSEntry *) b;
                    return [entry1.articleDate compare:entry2.articleDate];


                    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
                    //... do everything I've done before...
                    [pool drain];


                }];

                [_allEntries insertObject:entry atIndex:insertIdx];

                entries = 0;

            }                            

        }];

    }   

        //[doc release];
        //doc = nil;

}];

[doc release];
doc = nil;
[error release];

}
```

Comment: Maybe there is a memory leak somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Ray Wenderlich's site also has an article about the [advantages of various XML parsers](http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project). The GDataXML parser seems to have one of the larger memory footprints, and you might have to change to something like [TBXML](http://www.tbxml.co.uk/).

Comment: Thanks i tried the TMXML one and it still takes memory usage up to 32MB. The actual file is only 7MB so i cannot understand why it increases it up so much. Should i be considering a SAX parser? any working examples would be really appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't realised that TBXML is a DOM parser. You should try a SAX parser. The built in one, NSXMLParser, is a bit difficult to use, but I used code from the Big Nerd Ranch site (http://weblog.bignerdranch.com/?p=48) to learn it. The XML I parsed was only about 1 MB, but it handled it on an iPhone 3G which has very little memory. I assume that the memory increases because a DOM parser holds the XML document in memory, then creates many objects from it at the same time. The objects are likely larger than the XML representation.

Comment: Hi thanks do you have a working example i could view. Again thanks for you quick response.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a working example. It took me a few hours the first time I used that sample code to put together one for my app. It's not that pleasant to use, but if it can prevent your crash, it's worth it.